# Delete image from url Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

In my cloud functions, I'm trying to delete an image based on its url, but I think that I don't use correctly the API as I'm getting errors :

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.deleteImageWhenOfferDeleted = functions.firestore 
  .document('offers/{offerId}')
  .onDelete(async(snap, context) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')
    const deletedOffer = snap.data();
    var imageUrlToDelete = deletedOffer.imageUrl;
    await admin.storage.getPathStorageFromUrl(imageUrlToDelete).delete();

function getPathStorageFromUrl(url){
    const baseUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/muslim-coloc.appspot.com/o/";
    let imagePath = url.replace(baseUrl,"");
    const indexOfEndPath = imagePath.indexOf("?");
    imagePath = imagePath.substring(0,indexOfEndPath);
    imagePath = imagePath.replace("%2F","/");
    return imagePath;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing brackets after `storage` word.
You need to get an instance of storage object.

```
admin.storage.getReferenceFromUrl(...)
```

should be

```
admin.storage().getReferenceFromUrl(...)
```

BTW: Consider using TypeScript, because it catches errors like that during compilation.